# save data from a table with dynamic rows

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Thank you for viewing my post, I have a problem with dynamic rows, since I have this code that was created for a previous exercise, where I created a table in which the rows can be increased, my question is now how to save what is registered in the base of data in mysql.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#addMore').on('click', function() {
    var data = $("#tb tr:eq(1)").clone(true).appendTo("#tb");
    data.find("input").val('');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
    if (trIndex > 1) {
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    } else {
      alert("Sorry!! Can't remove first row!");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table table-hover small-text" id="tb">
  <tr class="tr-header">
    <th>Full Name</th>
    <th>Designation</th>
    <th>Mobile No.</th>
    <th>Email Id</th>
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" id="addMore" title="Add More Person"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="fullname[]" class="form-control"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="designation[]" class="form-control">
          <option value="" selected>Select Designation</option>
          <option value="Engineer">Engineer</option>
          <option value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="mobileno[]" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="emailid[]" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I leave here the demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/b2v9Lytq/1/

Comment: I made you a snippet and removed the loose </tr> you had. Why do you use such an ancient version of jQuery? Also you really should have `thead` and `tbody` tags

Comment: of the version, more than anything it is for the teacher is one that she passed us from the beginning and from that we have to start

Comment: Have a look at the dupes I posted